# Converting Multiple Dummy Variables into one Column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to convert a table that looks like this:

```
            Blue    Green    Red
Thing 1     No      Yes      No
Thing 2     Yes     No       No
Thing 3     Yes     No       No
```

Into this style:

```
            Color
Thing 1     Green
Thing 2     Blue
Thing 3     Blue
```

Is there a nice way to do this in python or pandas? And do these table styles have names?

Comment: The names for these approaches are "dummy" or "indicator" variables in the first case, and a categorical variable in the second.  See [`pandas.DataFrame.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html), for example, which performs the conversion in the opposite direction (categorical to dummies).

Comment: only need to add df.eq(‘yes')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use [idxmax](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
df.eq('Yes').idxmax(axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
Thing 1    Green
Thing 2     Blue
Thing 3     Blue
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 5):

If each row has exactly one 'yes', you can do

```
df.eq('Yes') @ df.columns
```

Output:

```
Thing 1    Green
Thing 2     Blue
Thing 3     Blue
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df.where(df.eq('Yes')).stack().reset_index(level=1)['level_1']

Thing 1    Green
Thing 2     Blue
Thing 3     Blue
Name: level_1, dtype: object
```